# How to resize a LeadRasterDlgFile dialog box in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 application that is using leadtools 14.  The codes references the member ShowDirectoryDlg from the Class LeadRasterDlgFile.  The end users have requested this diaglog box be made larger.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this library, and there was no easy way to search for LeadRasterDlgFile on the website. And anyway, I assume that you have scoured the documentation for a way to do this.

This only leaves Windows API calls. You have to use a timer set to fire 1ms after setting the timer to Enabled. Then you call your function. In the timer event loop, use FindWindow() or FindWindowsEx() to get your dialogue window. Next, use MoveWindow() to resize the window. You might also want to resize the child windows. Use GetWindow() to identify child windows. Use Spy++ to check the child window IDs.

Note that this will only work in the compiled application - not in the IDE.

The problem with this is that it is possible that the dialogue does not use standard Windows windows. You will find this out with Spy++.